# SQL syntax error initializing DB before unit Tests

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have created a .sql for preparing my DB for testing.

here a part of the .sql which produces the error:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS announcement;
CREATE TABLE announcement (
   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   date datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   title varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   content mediumtext,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES announcement WRITE;
INSERT INTO announcement VALUES (1,'2015-07-29 10:59:16','Test Anno ','some text');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

when executed in Mysql Workbench this scipt works fine.

however when executed via hibernate:

```
String sqlScript = readFile("dump.sql", Charset.forName("UTF8"));
//System.err.println(sqlScript);
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("BEGIN " + sqlScript + "END;");
q.executeUpdate();
```

I get:

```
2015-08-06 16:15:55 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS announcement;
CREATE TABLE announcement (
  id int(11) NO' at line 1
```

I am using:

```
Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", true);
```

Can someone help me out here?
thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove the NOT NULL after int(11)? It sounds like SQL isn't liking that. With AUTO_INCREMENT on, you don't need the NOT NULL anyway.

Comment: just wondering do you need a space before `END;`?.....  ` END;`

Comment: I suspect you need to execute statements in your `.sql` file one by one.

Comment: -LeePresswood NOT NULL needed here, does not change the behaviour though.

-Ankit wouln'd harm to add it. 

-mustaccio I hope I will not need to do that.. would make the use of a .sql scipt useless. I'll look in to that.

Comment: @mustaccio If I only execute the first statement 'Drop table ..' I also get the same error. `2015-08-06 16:36:45 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS announcement;
 END' at line 1`

Comment: You cannot use the compound statement (`BEGIN ... END`) outside a stored procedure, I don't think.

Comment: @mustaccio I am affraid you where right as posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312697/hibernate-multiple-native-sql-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by mustaccio `BEGIN` and `END` statements are not allowed outside of stored procedueres. See: [Hibernate multiple native SQL statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312697/hibernate-multiple-native-sql-statements)