# Is there a way in hibernate that can manipulate many query in one String

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

Im using hibernate in my web project. And Im executing this line of `String` in `createSQLQuery(queryString)`. below is the value I assigned in `queryString`:

```
DROP TABLE monthlyevaluatedbudgettabletemp;
DROP TABLE monthlyadjustedbudgettabletemp;

CREATE TABLE monthlyevaluatedbudgettabletemp (budgetid bigint NOT NULL,
  approvedbudget numeric(19,2),
  april numeric(19,2),
  august numeric(19,2),
  budgetforyear bigint NOT NULL,
  december numeric(19,2),
  february numeric(19,2),
  january numeric(19,2),
  july numeric(19,2),
  june numeric(19,2),
  march numeric(19,2),
  may numeric(19,2),
  november numeric(19,2),
  october numeric(19,2),
  september numeric(19,2),
  branchid integer,
  accountid bigint,
  budgetlastyear bigint);

CREATE TABLE monthlyadjustedbudgettabletemp (adjustedid bigint NOT NULL,
  april numeric(19,2),
  august numeric(19,2),
  december numeric(19,2),
  february numeric(19,2),
  january numeric(19,2),
  july numeric(19,2),
  june numeric(19,2),
  march numeric(19,2),
  may numeric(19,2),
  november numeric(19,2),
  october numeric(19,2),
  september numeric(19,2),
  yeartodatemonth character varying(255),
  budgetid bigint);

INSERT INTO monthlyevaluatedbudgettabletemp SELECT * FROM monthlyevaluatedbudgettable where budgetforyear=2017;
INSERT INTO monthlyadjustedbudgettabletemp SELECT a.* from monthlyadjustedbudgettable as a join monthlyevaluatedbudgettable as e on a.budgetid=e.budgetid where e.budgetforyear = 2017

UPDATE monthlyevaluatedbudgettabletemp SET budgetforyear=2017,budgetlastyear=2016,april=0.00,approvedbudget=0.00,august=0.00,february=0.00,january=0.00,july=0.00,june=0.00,march=0.00,may=0.00,november=0.00,october=0.00,september=0.00,december=0.00;

UPDATE monthlyadjustedbudgettabletemp SET january=0.00,february=0.00,march=0.00,april=0.00,may=0.00,june=0.00,july=0.00,august=0.00,september=0.00,november=0.00,
october=0.00,december=0.00;
```

now when I run it with `createSQLQuery(queryString).executeUpdate();`. I'm encountering this kind of error.

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
```

Now my question, is there a way that I can manipulate query in one shot String. or do I have to separate each query statement and execute it one by one. It is like I want to execute a `.sql` file in hibernate.

Comment: [Hibernate multiple native SQL statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312697/hibernate-multiple-native-sql-statements)
I guess you need to run these queries one by one.

Comment: why use hibernate for such kind of operations? Use JDBC please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run multiple native queries at one go in Hibernate.

You will have to separate the queries and then run them individually.

That's how you would do it in JDBC as well.

Answer (score 1):

So I came up with this kind of code to share with other. But I will check the Answer of @Pritam Banerjee for giving me a nice answer. I `split` my `String` by ";" symbol to separate each statement and I use a `loop` to execute it one by one.

```
String[] splitQueryStr = queryString.split(";");
    for (String queryStr : splitQueryStr) {
        try {
            getSession().beginTransaction();
            getSession().createSQLQuery(queryStr).executeUpdate();
            getSession().getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
            he.printStackTrace();
            throw new HibernateException("Hibernate Error");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new Exception();
        } 
    }
```

It works fine in me. Thanks for the comments and answers. Appreciate it.